HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") siempre es null
Tengo una aplicación Blazor Web App con autentificación con cuentas individuales que sobre google. Y esto funciona bien.
Ahora quiero poder enviar email a través de la API de gmail (no quiero usar smtp ni crear una contraseña de aplicación), he habilitado todo lo necesario en google, e instalado en las API de gmail.
Este es mi fragmento del program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication( options =>  
                    {
                        
                        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
                    { googleOptions.ClientId = "xxxxx.googleusercontent.com";
                        googleOptions.ClientSecret = "xxxxx";
                        googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://mail.google.com/");
                        googleOptions.SaveTokens = true;
                        googleOptions.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
                        {
                            // Guardar el token de acceso para usar la API de Gmail
                            var accessToken = ctx.AccessToken;
                            var refreshToken = ctx.RefreshToken;
              // Aquí puedes registrar los tokens temporalmente para verificar que se están guardando
              // Almacenar el token temporalmente en HttpContext.Items
              ctx.HttpContext.Items["access_token"] = accessToken;
                            
              Console.WriteLine("AccessToken: " + accessToken);
              Console.WriteLine("RefreshToken: " + refreshToken);
              return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };
                    })
        .AddIdentityCookies();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

Aqui accessToken tiene un valor, pero cuando lo voy a usar un webapi
[HttpGet]
    [Route("Envia")]
    public async Task EnviarCorreo()
        {
    
        if (User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated)
            {
            var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            if (accessToken != null)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Token de acceso: " + accessToken);
                }
            else
                {
                Console.WriteLine("No se pudo obtener el token de acceso.");
                }
            }
        else
            {
            Console.WriteLine("El usuario no está autenticado.");
            }
      //blablabla
       }

Aqui siempre es null, y el usuario esta logueado con una cuenta de google
Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias
